# NGINX 403 forbidden with php

Tags: php, nginx

My server setup with NGINX and php.

I need to run a php script, that connecting two databases usig `mysql_connect($host,$user,$pwd)`. Its a little bit long process and it takes large time to process all.

All connection are become success, but the script not giving result for complete operation, when i run that file it showing (processing circle is rotating), after some particular time stop execution and showing message `"403 Forbidden"`

Already set the following:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', '0');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

403 error means that your nginx not configured correctly.

If you need to execute long-running php script better to use CLI for this, for example

```
php script.php
```

or

```
nohup php script.php 2>&1 &
```

Comment: thnks for your reply. But can't use this cmd because this file need UI interaction